# How to set Cil.useLogicalOperators to true?

Tags: ocaml, cil

Consider this code

```
Open Cil

Cil.useLogicalOperators := true

let fct op =
match op with
  LAnd|LOr       -> true
  | _                       -> false
```

I'm trying to use `LAnd` and `LOr` from the type [`binop`](https://cil-project.github.io/cil/doc/html/cil/api/Cil.html#TYPEbinop). These two can be used only if `Cil.useLogicalOperators` is true.

```
|   LAnd    (*  logical and. Unlike other expressions this one does not always evaluate both operands. If you want to use these, you must set Cil.useLogicalOperators.  *)
|   LOr (*  logical or. Unlike other expressions this one does not always evaluate both operands. If you want to use these, you must set Cil.useLogicalOperators.   *)
```

So I must set `Cil.useLogicalOperators`.

```
val useLogicalOperators : bool ref
```

Is this code mentionned above is correct ?
Does it set `Cil.useLogicalOperators` to true ?

Comment: We won't read the doc of a package we don't know to answer your question. You need to provide all the available informations in your question to allow us to be able to answer. Please edit your question to provide such informations.

Comment: I tried to makey my problem a bit more clear, with no need to read the package. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're asking how to set a global variable that is itself a reference.

In this case, no, a global assignment always start with `let`

In your case you need to write

```ml
let () = Cil.useLogicalOperators := true
```

In OCaml, files are compiled top to bottom and values are evaluated at once. Here, `let () = ...` is a value so it will be evaluated before the rest of the following code. You can check it with:

```ml
let () = Format.eprintf "%b@." !Cil.useLogicalOperators
let () = Cil.useLogicalOperators := true
let () = Format.eprintf "%b@." !Cil.useLogicalOperators
```